# A man who doesnt Advertise himself- Single Word

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who doesn't want to advertise himself? He may be somebody special but doesn't like to talk about his achievement or advertise himself. What is the Adjective that describes such a trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unpretentious:** 
Not attempting to impress others with an appearance of greater importance, talent, or culture than is actually possessed. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unpretentious))

Example:
‘in spite of his fame he was thoroughly unpretentious’
More example sentences

**Self-effacing:** Not claiming attention for oneself; retiring and modest. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-effacing))

Example: his demeanour was self-effacing, gracious, and polite.

You could also say *[reticent](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reticent)*, *[unostentatious](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unostentatious)* or *[unassuming](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unassuming)*.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the person was [**modest**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modest):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : placing a moderate estimate on one's abilities or worth
>   **1 b** : neither bold nor self-assertive : tending toward diffidence

Alternatively, depending on the specific interpretation, they could also be [**humble**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humble):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : not proud or haughty : not arrogant or assertive
>   **2** : reflecting, expressing, or offered in a spirit of deference or submission
>   // a *humble* apology

Comment: I remember a word having the word 'advertise' in that, e.g. non-advertising or something. I want to emphasize on 'Advertising'. What is the opposite of this- A man who always advertises about himself?

Comment: @Tanvir **Hidden** or **secretive** might work if you're looking for something qualitatively different. But my own words do mean the opposite of *advertising*. In fact, the answer you accepted simply provides synonyms of the words I gave (*modest* even appears in the definition of *self-effacing*). None of them (in that answer or this) correspond to the different meaning you now say you are looking for.

Comment: 'Unpretentious' or 'self-effacing' are very suitable words for my case, as mentioned above by another guy

Answer (score 1):

I'd use one of 'humble' or 'modest'

Answer (score 1):

How about **understated**?

From TFD:

> **[understated](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/understated)**: not obvious; subtle // restrained; de-emphasized; low-key

From Cambridge:

> **[understated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understated)**: not trying to attract attention or impress people, e.g., *He's very elegant, in an understated way.*

Example:

> Jane was always **understated** when it came to the value of her contributions.

It's implicit in saying that Jane is **understated** that she has an understated personality, manner, approach.

Comment: I've never seen this used for individuals. Their drums, arguments, charm, pitches, black dresses, even organisations ... but not individuals. Will return to check whether you supply a valid example from a reasonable source..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's common in the U.S. to characterize people as *understated*. Look forward to the results of your research.

Comment: Will return to check whether **you** supply a valid example from a reasonable source.... It's _your_ answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the comment. It helped me strengthen the answer.

Comment: The reasonable source being? I've found 3 relevant hits for "John was understated". But 'Everything about John was understated yet glaringly obvious at the same time.' seems fine, and relevant here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, would you mind sending me the source of the sentence you've referenced? I'd like to add it the answer, if you wouldn't mind. I need to improve at finding relevant sources. Thank you.

Comment: It's apparentli in [A Life Restarted
– Zoe Waters](https://www.scribd.com/book/210956663/A-Life-Restarted). A Google search for ["Everything about John was understated yet glaringly"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=0BmkXvn0OcudlwSbjZSgDg&q=+%22Everything+about+John+was+understated+yet+glaringly%22&oq=+%22Everything+about+John+was+understated+yet+glaringly%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoFCCEQqwJQ_wpYhj1g-j9oAHAAeACAAXKIAfgCkgEDMi4ymAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj5nLLXt4PpAhXLzoUKHZsGBeQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) leads to the link....

Comment: And the example happily appeared on the first page of my initial Google search, for ["John was understated"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=2RmkXp2EG72C1fAPyaeY8AY&q=%22John+was+understated%22&oq=%22John+was+understated%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQqwI6BQghEKABUMCcBljvwQZgtMYGaANwAHgAgAFpiAH-ApIBAzQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjd1Ljbt4PpAhU9QRUIHckTBm4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5).